# Resize inDesign document form A4 to 210x285

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have created a catalogue for a cliend in A4 210x297. It has default setting for margins, and i think that by default there is no bleed. They want me to resiye it to 210x285 with 3mm bleed. How can i do that and remain the same scale, and equal margins on top and bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look under `File > Document Setup`, you can adjust the page size and bleed settings. Your margins should also be retained relative to the page size.
If you do want to adjust the margins, select the Master Page you want to edit, and go to `Layout > Margins and Columns`.
**NOTE:** Future questions of this nature are probably better suited, and will be answered more quickly, if you post them in [Graphcic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).